# Solidity Address Book Smart Contract returns error when trying to create new mapping entry

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I'm learning Solidity and I am trying to make an Address Book smart contract. Right now the code allows the user to create an account of sorts using the createBook function.

```
contract AddressBook {

    struct ownerInfo{
        string ownerAlias;
    }

    string[] Alias;

    mapping(address => ownerInfo) public ownerToAlias;

    function createBook(string memory _ownerAlias) public{
        for(uint i = 0; i <= Alias.length; i++) {
            require(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_ownerAlias)) != keccak256(abi.encodePacked(Alias[i])));
            ownerToAlias[msg.sender] = ownerInfo(_ownerAlias);
            Alias.push(_ownerAlias);
        }
        
    }

}
```

There are no errors when compiling or deploying, but the createBook function returns an error. The problem seems to come from the require() function which I'm using to check whether the input'd name is already in use.

I expected the code to work when I pass in "Address Book Name" for the first time, and return an error when I try to pass in the same string again.

Answer (score 0):

The condition of the for loop needs to be: `for(uint i = 0; i < Alias.length; i++)`
because as it is right now the loop will continue forever, because you push a new element to the Alias array at the end, the condition will always be true. The length of the Array will always be equal to i as they both increment by one after every loop

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing that out. I fixed that and the error is gone. However, it seems to allow duplicate names. I've also added a function to get the name I entered but it doesn't return anything.